# Joomla Administration Login Custom Error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, recaptcha

I'm using Google  reCAPTCHA on joomla admini login section, Validation works fine.

Captcha validation added to `administrator/components/com_login/models/login.php`

```
 $privatekey = "myprivatekey";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (
        $privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        JRequest::getVar('recaptcha_challenge_field', '', 'method', 'recaptcha_challenge_field'),
        JRequest::getVar('recaptcha_response_field', '', 'method', 'recaptcha_response_field')
    );

 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    //die('Incorrect Captcha...');
 }else{     
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => JRequest::getVar('username', '', 'method', 'username'),
        'password' => JRequest::getVar('passwd', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW)
    );
    $this->setState('credentials', $credentials);
 }
```

What should I use instead of `//die('Incorrect Captcha...');` to output **Invalid Captcha!** Error in login page?

[image: Error Sample Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->enqueueMessage('Incorrect Captcha...', 'error');
$app->redirect(JURI::base());
```

Comment: replace the line //die('Incorrect Captcha...'); with the code I have provided above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JError` to show the error when the output in invalid.

For example:

```
JError::raiseError( JText::_( 'Invalid Captcha' ));
```

For more methods you can see this [JError](http://docs.joomla.org/JError/11.1)

Comment: thank you, this is also working but its not showing the error as i wanted.

Comment: just pass the redirect link to that function you will get as you wanted